# "Fixing" the first few columns in an SWT table to prevent them from scrolling horizontally

Tags: java, swt

We have implemented a table-based editor with an SWT tree table. It pretty much does what we want it to, except that we can't find a way to ensure that the first few columns remain at their position when the user scrolls horizontally (so that one can identify the row being edited).

There are a number of third-party table controls in various degrees of being incomplete or abandoned, and a snippet that shows how to use two tables (which get out of sync when they're being scrolled vertically).

What's the best way to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

This 'official' SWT [snippet](http://dev.eclipse.org/viewcvs/index.cgi/org.eclipse.swt.snippets/src/org/eclipse/swt/snippets/Snippet234.java?view=co) does what you want to do, at least on my machine - it does not get out of sync on vertical scroll. But the price is a second scrollbar - way ugly. To prevent this, you can add the style `SWT.NO_SCROLL` in the constructor of the left table.

To improve the thing you will have to add a Listener on `SWT.Traverse` to both Tables, which syncs them if the user navigated using keys, something like this:

```
  leftTable.addListener(SWT.Traverse, new Listener() {

     public void handleEvent( Event event ) {
        rightTable.setTopIndex(leftTable.getTopIndex());
     }
  });
```

I wouldn't go with another Table implementation, since you lose the biggest advantage you have with SWT: using a native widget, which looks and feels 'right' in each OS. If you want to do that anyway, [Grid](http://www.eclipse.org/nebula/widgets/grid/grid.php) from the Nebula project is much more mature than the alpha tag implies. Don't know if it can do what you want, though.

Answer (score 0):

the "syncing problem" only appears on MacOs based SWT. If your target platform is windows you should have no problem with the given SWT-Snippet. There will be more listeners to register on both tables to synchronise all occuring events (collapse, expand, mouse scroll, etc.)